# How to validate :created_at in model (RAILS 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

```
irb(main):044:0> i1.created_at
=> Thu, 24 Apr 2014 02:41:15 UTC +00:00
irb(main):045:0> i2.created_at
=> Thu, 24 Apr 2014 02:41:15 UTC +00:00
irb(main):046:0> i1.created_at == i2.created_at
=> false
irb(main):047:0> i1.created_at.to_time.to_i == i2.created_at.to_time.to_i
=> true
```

Seems not to work `validates_uniqueness_of :created_at`
because

```
irb(main):046:0> i1.created_at == i2.created_at
=> false
```

How to validate created_at? Don't want to save with the same date.

+++ UPDATE +++

```
irb(main):048:0> i1.created_at.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
irb(main):049:0> i2.created_at.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

Comment: A bit OT, but I'm interested to know why you need `created_at` on two different instances to be unique?

Comment: Some Items have two identical data in my DB only created_at are different (all the smae except USEC). I only need one so, I want to make it unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they might have different precision milliseconds.

Refer to the post: [Testing ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone objects for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512876/testing-activesupporttimewithzone-objects-for-equality)

Chances are the millisecond values would be unequal.

```
puts i1.created_at.usec
puts i2.created_at.usec
```

Comment: irb(main):050:0> i1.created_at.usec
=> 311714
irb(main):051:0> i2.created_at.usec
=> 312779
yup, you're right. thank you

Comment: You may write custom validators to handle this. Refer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html. Section 6.2 Custom Methods.

Comment: Any hint how can I make it work with custom validators? Thank you for the link, I checked it, but still have no clue how to make it created_at unique. sorry for bothering you & thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you are getting `concurrent requests`, there are chances that you may have multiple entries in the table which are created at same time and will have same time stamps.

As you said, if you don't want to save with the same `date`, you can put a `lock` while saving the entries, removing the possibility of creating two entries at same time. In that case `validates_uniqueness_of :created_at` should also work.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. Have to wait till next day, cuz of cron :)
Again, thank you & I'll accept it tomorrow if it's gonna work.

Comment: I tried with validates_uniqueness_of :) doesn't work :) because usec are different.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :asin, :domain, :formatted_price, :user_id, :created_at

  validate :double_dates

  private

  def double_dates
    if Item.where(:user_id => self.user_id, :asin => self.asin, :domain => self.domain).where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today).length >= 1
      errors.add(:created_at, "no double dates")
    end
  end
end
```